# Restore a dump file from a different server, with a different name

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, datapump

I `Expdp` a user with the name `user_prd` for example. I copied the dump file to another server, and I want to restore it with the name `user_hom`.

I tried `remap_schema` with no succes ( Im a SQL DBA, so it's hard to understand that schema is the name of the user, that is the database in SQL. I'm slowly learning )

I thought to rename the schema, but [As said here, it's not a so good idea.](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:30020192108317)

I read somewhere about `fromuser touser`. Is this right?

I could use `remap_schema` with users from inside the same server, like, there was the `user_prd`, and I just created the `user_hom`, using remap.

---

EDIT1:

I'm trying this for now:

```
IMP SYSTEMUSER/PASS@TNS FILE=<myFile>.dmp fromuser=OriginalUser_prd touser=New_User_hom
```

and:

```
bla bla bla IMP-0034 error
```

Answer (score 0):

> #### IMP-00034: Warning: FromUser "string" not found in export file
>
> Cause: The user specified a FROMUSER name that does not exist in export file.
>
> Action: Correct the FROMUSER specification.

Data pump is newer alternatives to "exp" and "imp" utilities used prior to Oracle 10G. The newer version is faster and efficient with more flexibilities.

You can use `REMAP_SCHEMA` parameter in `impdp` to achieve the goal.

> #### REMAP_SCHEMA
>
> **Purpose**
>
> Loads all objects from the source schema into a target schema.

For details, [REMAP_SCHEMA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523.htm#SUTIL927)

Comment: I just can't use EXPDP ( sorry, i learned this now haha ). I got an error message saying `ORA-39143 may be an original export dump file `, and reading on the internet, it says I need to use the deprecated IMP. It's really hard to find something about oracle. In SQL Server this is a really simple task.

Comment: I tried now `imp <TheUserIWantTheDatabaseToBe/Pass>@ORCL file=DumpFile.dmp  full=y` and still no succes. Jesus. The user I want the database to be was created already. But I got the `IMP-00003 and ORA-01435` error messages

Comment: `imp <TheUserIWantTheDatabaseToBe/Pass>@ORCL file=DumpFile.dmp fromuser=TheCorrectUser touser=TheUserIcreatedToBeTheDatabase`. I THINK IT WORKED THIS WAY. HELL YEASS. but just a question. When i say the I want to import a user, using another user. What does this mean? If I want to export users using the `system`, is there a problem on it?

Comment: "In SQL Server this is a really simple task. "   It's a really simple task in Oracle as well,  but you have to take off your Microsoft goggles.

Comment: `imp user1/pass@db file=1.dmp fromuser=X touser=Y`
Here **user1** is an account under which the imp tool connects to the database.
If user1 has the the right privileges - IMP_FULL_DATABASE role, then this user can do the import from one user to another.